# nginx PHP User Profile Rewriting

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting

I'm trying to rewrite my url profile URL's to be clean and not contain parameters, at least to the user. I'm using a nginx server and having some trouble getting this to work.

Site Example:
http://website.com/subfolder/

Profile Link:
http://website.com/subfolder/profile.php

What works:
http://website.com/subfolder/profile.php?username=Bobby

What I want to work:
http://website.com/subfolder/Bobby

The code block in my website config:

```
location /subfolder/ {
    if ($query_string ~ "^username=([A-Za-z0-9]+)$"){
        rewrite ^/profile.php$ http://website.com/subfolder/%1 redirect;
    }
}
```

Comment: just one hint, you are doing the contrary, you try to rewrite internally a request with a query string to something that PHP will not understand. You need to write the final URL in your PHP code, and manage the rewriting from this new url to the query string version internally in Nginx.

Answer (score 0):

Your redirect is almost correct. Just little cosmetic changes.

```
location = /subfolder/profile.php {
    if ($arg_username) {
        return 301 /subfolder/$arg_username/;
    }
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9001;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

Now, how regilero told, you need to parse /subfolder/Username/ inside script or you can do it by nginx

```
location ~ ^/subfolder/(?<username>.+)/$ {
   rewrite ^(.*)$ /subfolder/profile.php?username=$username break;
   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9001;
   include fastcgi_params;
   fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $uri$is_args$args;
}
```

2 important notes: rewrite `break` keyword protecting from redirect loop; `fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI` usually is `$request_uri` (in fastcgi_params), but it's original URI, so we need to change it.